# dependencies in shiny objects

Tags: r, shiny

In my app, the user needs to pick a folder, and in that folder he needs to pick a file (the suffix of the file name is '.seg')

This code is working-

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    # select a folder
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px',
                            selectInput("pick_a_folder", label = '', selected='choose a folder',
                                        choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose a folder',
                                                                     basename(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)))), 
                                                           c('choose a folder', 
                                                             basename(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE))))))),
    # select a file
    column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px', 
                            conditionalPanel(condition='!(input.pick_a_folder=="choose a folder")', 
                                             uiOutput('fileselection'))))
  ))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # dinamic file selection. find the files list after folder is choosen
  output$fileselection <- renderUI({
    selectInput('pick_file', '', selected = 'choose a file',
                choices=setNames(as.list(c('choose a file',basename(list.files(path=input$pick_a_folder,recursive=FALSE, pattern='\\.seg$')))), 
                                 c('choose a file',basename(list.files(path = input$pick_a_folder, recursive = FALSE, pattern='\\.seg$')))))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue is that if I add a folder to the working directory after I ran the code, it will not appear.
So I tried to move the folder selection to the server, and make it dependent on a refresh button, but I get an error

> Error in list.files: invalid 'path' argument
>   this is my code-

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # refresh butten for root directory
  column(1, absolutePanel(fixed=TRUE, actionButton("refresh_wd", "refresh"))),

  # select a folder
  column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px', uiOutput('folderselection'))),

  # select a file
  column(2, absolutePanel(fixed = TRUE, width = '180px', 
                          conditionalPanel(condition='!(input.pick_a_folder=="choose a folder")', 
                                           uiOutput('fileselection'))))
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # refresh root directory
  wd_folders <- eventReactive(input$refresh_wd, {
    basename(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE))
  })

  output$folderselection <- renderUI({
    selectInput('pick_a_folder', '', selected = 'choose a folder',
                choices = setNames(as.list(c('choose a folder', wd_folders())),
                                   c('choose a folder', wd_folders())))
  })

  # dinamic file selection. find the file list after folder is choosen
  output$fileselection <- renderUI({
    selectInput('pick_a_file', '', selected = 'choose a file',
                choices=setNames(as.list(c('choose a file',basename(list.files(path=input$pick_a_folder,recursive=FALSE, pattern='\\.seg$')))), 
                                 c('choose a file',basename(list.files(path = input$pick_a_folder, recursive = FALSE, pattern='\\.seg$')))))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you want the user to pick a file on the server side, or to pick a file from their own computer?

Comment: from where my script is, on the server

Comment: So `fileInput()` is not what you're looking for then : http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

Comment: Also: how important is it that the app updates the list of folders during a single session?

Comment: I'm not using `fileInput()`. did you mean I should?
it's important. my script runs all thew time on our server, and is used to analyze medical results, every time a new result comes in, a new folder is created, I need the users to be able to refresh the wd.

Comment: `fileInput()` is for allowing the user to upload. This is a different situation. But you should keep in mind that it doesn't run "all the time". Each time a user access the app, a new instance is fired up. So only when a user needs to see an updated list of folders while working, this is an important problem.

Comment: I checked, and if I run the script on the server before the folder is created, it will not appear even if it was created before this specific instance was lunched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136158/discussion-between-joris-meys-and-t-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `eventReactive()` the list of folders and even the folder selection will only be displayed after somebody clicked on the 'Refresh' button. You can avoid this by using `ignoreNULL = FALSE` :

```
wd_folders <- eventReactive(input$refresh_wd, {
    basename(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

If you don't do this, the value of `wd_folders()` will be NULL to start with, so your condition for your `conditionalPanel` is fulfilled (it's not "select a folder") and hence your app tries to read the files in directory NULL. This gives you your error.

If you want to be extra safe, you can add `validate(need())` to the UI rendering as well, eg:

```
output$fileselection <- renderUI({
    validate(need(input$pick_a_folder, label = "Pick a folder first"))
    validate(need(dir.exists(input$pick_a_folder),
                  label = "Something went wrong. Contact me."))
    selectInput('pick_a_file', '', selected = 'choose a file',
                ...)
  })
```

This isn't necessary to fix your problem, but I find it good practice in Shiny.

Comment: Thank you! works fine now. I'll read about `validate(need())` before I start using it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example that auto refresh the folders every 5 seconds.
It does still produce an initial warning about `path` being invalid for the reasons @JoriMeys explained.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    column(1,
           absolutePanel(fixed=TRUE,

                         textOutput('wd'),

                         uiOutput('folderselection'),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition='!(input.pick_a_folder=="choose a folder")', 
                             uiOutput('fileselection'))
           )
    )
)
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$wd <- renderText(basename(
        list.files(path = input$pick_a_folder,
                   recursive=FALSE)
    )
    )
    button <- reactiveTimer(intervalMs = 5000)
    # refresh root directory
    wd_folders <- reactive({
        button()
        basename(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE))
    })

    output$folderselection <- renderUI({
        selectInput('pick_a_folder', '',
                    choices = c('choose a folder', wd_folders()
                    )
        )
    })

    # dinamic file selection. find the file list after folder is choosen
    output$fileselection <- renderUI({
        selectInput('pick_a_file', '', 
                    selected = 'choose a file',
                    choices=c('choose a file',
                              basename(list.files(path = input$pick_a_folder,recursive=FALSE))))
    })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what you did too.